# what will happen if i call ajax function recursively? it may cause any issues.

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ajaxcall();
    });
    function ajaxcall(){
    $.ajax({
          url: 'test.php',
            success: function(data) { 
                data = data.split(':');
                $('#hours').html(data[0]);
                $('#minutes').html(data[1]);
                $('#seconds').html(data[2]);
                ajaxcall();
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    <span id="hours">0</span>:<span id="minutes">0</span>:<span id="seconds">0</span>
```

In this code i called the ajax function onsuccess, so it will be infinite loop. It cause any problems?

Comment: An infinite loop is always undesirable. Your browser will crash.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: It depends on what your definition of "causing a problem" looks like. Letting your users [DoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) your server might pose a problem.

Comment: You're better off using an interval. `setInterval("ajaxcall",500)`

Comment: @MarcusRecck - I see no benefit to using setInterval over a recursive call here. With either the biggest risk is the browser's memory management and garbage collection.

Comment: With the interval it wouldn't be called as many times as the recursive call, it would at least give the server a nice break between each request.

Comment: `setTimeout` is far better than `setInterval` when doing asynchronous operations to avoid piling up multiple operations in the event of a long delay due to network connection or server load.

Comment: `setInterval(ajaxcall, 500)` would be better. @j08691, the benefit is that the browser won't run out of memory when you use `setInterval`, whereas in the case of infinite recursion, it *will* run out of memory. It is also a rather bizarre and non-obvious pattern. Recursion is normally used for some specific cases and this  really doesn't fit the pattern.

Comment: setInterval is a good idea if you forget about using a recursive approach. Have a look at Vivin answer.

Comment: @j08691 I was wrong about the call using up memory. Totally forgot that the call is asynchronous. Still, I think using `setInterval` makes more sense here.

Comment: But for now it's working without any problem, actually my function is to display the timer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>This will cause your browser to run out of memory eventually and crash because each call will be saved on the call-stack.</s> I was wrong; the callback is asynchronous and so control will leave the parent function. If you're trying to update the time, I recommend doing something like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(ajaxcall, 1000); //calls ajaxcall every 1000 microseconds
});

function ajaxcall(){
   $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        success: function(data) { 
            data = data.split(':');
            $('#hours').html(data[0]);
            $('#minutes').html(data[1]);
            $('#seconds').html(data[2]);
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: Yes, that will do. Having the method being called every second is the right way of building a clock, timer or any other time-based system in a web page instead of looping endlessly. A recursive function MUST end, it can't be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing bad is going to happen. It'll make the ajax call, wait for it to return, then make another forever. There is nothing wrong with that itself. Just be careful that your server-side operation is not too heavy, and that you're not transferring too much data not to waste too much bandwidth.

If you ever want to be able to stop it, you could make a variable to define whether to keep doing the calls, and just turn it off whenever.

```
var keepCalling = true;

function ajaxCall() {
    if (!keepCalling)
        return;

    //ajax call...
}
```

Setting `keepCalling` to `false` will stop the calls after the current one is complete.

Comment: The browser will eventually run out of memory. It may take some time, but it *will* happen. There's only so many calls you can keep on the call stack.

Comment: Just do this: `function recursive() {recursive();}`, because that's what is essentially happening in the OP's code. It's just that it's happening at a slower rate.

Comment: That's the thing. I don't think it's the same as a recursive function. I'm thinking it might not build on the same stack.

Comment: Oh wait, you're absolutely right. Since it's asynchronous control already leaves the function.